# Accessing plugin functionality within WP REST API

Tags: plugins, rest-api

I'm using the WP REST API to trigger a task from an AJAX request, my callback function attempts to trigger an action found within a plugin, however, that plugin doesn't appear to have loaded.

The following code is within my `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {

    register_rest_route('foo/v1', '/capture-payments', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => [$this, 'capturePayments'],
    ));

});

public static function capturePayments($request) {

    // this action doesn't load, because the plugin hasn't loaded
    if ( ! has_action('name_of_plugin_action') ) {
        return new \WP_Error('payment_capture_not_available', 'Payment capture is not available', array('status' => 500));
    }

    ...

}
```

My question is, is there a way to load the plugins for this API request, such that I can access their functionality as I would within a normal theme?

Edit 1:

It might be worth noting that this used within the admin, for purely backend purposes.

Comment: Where are you adding this action?

Comment: `has_action` is checking if a particular hook as been used for `add_action()`, but that doesn't appear to be what you're using it for. Do you mean `function_exists()`. Also, this code has `public static function`, which implies it's in a class. Is this code actually in a class?

Comment: My code is all within `functions.php`. The plugin in question exposes an action that I want to trigger using `do_action('name_of_plugin_action')`, which is what I'm checking using `has_action()`, I want to make sure the action exists before I continue, and it seems I'm using that correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured out the problem, after trying a load of things I wanted to double check plugins weren't being loaded at all within the REST API.

I added some rudimentary debugging to the plugin in question and I saw that the plugin was indeed being loaded, my issue was that in these conditions the plugin itself wasn't exposing functionality it would do under a normal request.

The `do_action` I wanted to achieve therefore was failing, as it hadn't been registered. I simply invoked the class that registered the action and now my code works as desired.